# Page build failed: Date is not a valid datetime jekyll

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll

I use Jekyll for blogging and github to store my files.

I uploaded a .md file to post a new article like I usually do and I keep getting a Date is not a valid datetime error along with an email that says:
The page build failed with the following error:

The value 'nil' was passed to a date-related filter that expects valid dates in `/_layouts/post.html` or one of its layouts. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-date-is-not-a-valid-datetime/.

I don't have /_layouts/post.html on my repository.

I repeat the process with another md file but get the same thing.

Here's my GitHub repository https://github.com/kevinolega/minimalchanges

When I go to the settings I'm being asked to go to the same link.

I'm new to troubleshooting Jekyll.

Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In your `Gemfile` you have the `gem "minima"` and also in `_config`: `theme: minima`. So you are using jekyll [themes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/#overriding-theme-defaults).

In this case the `/_layouts/post.html` path is referring to the **minima** `post.html` layout.

You can serve your Jekyll instance locally and debug it properly with `bundle exec jekyll serve`, the error messages are pretty self-explanatory.